# how to open all bookmarks of a folder using vimperator?

Tags: firefox, vimperator

I want to open all bookmarks from a particular bookmark folder using vimperator in firefox. Is there any **key binding** for it?

Answer (score 4):

It can done by adding bookmark using any category,
-**folder** or -**keyword** or -**tag** or -**title**

Goto the page you want to bookmark. then,

```
:bmark -tag tagname
```

Now, you can open all bookmarks of a same category by

```
:bmarks! -tag tagname
```